# 'GZipStream' could not be found - reference issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzipstream

I can't get to use GZipStream class in my C# ASP.NET 4.5 application.

I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'GZipStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried using `using System.IO;` but the `System.IO.Compression` is not available in the "Reference Manager" in visual studio. I right click on the object name to see if Visual Studio finds the relevant reference but it does not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not in `System.IO.Compression.dll` (it's for ZIP archives), `GZipStream` but in `System.dll` assembly. Add `using System.IO.Compression`.

Comment: add your answer and I will accept

Comment: You may accept Ozik answer, more or less same content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to add reference to `System.dll` assembly and `using System.IO.Compression` namespace.

MSDN: [GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Right but I guess he already has a reference to System.dll! :)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is not the same as the dll name,You need to add a dll reference to the assembly, `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`

Comment: No, System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly is for ZipFile not for a _simple_ gzip stream (it's just in System.dll)